# How to use Android FusedLocationProviderClient to update based on distance

Tags: android, android-location

I want my Android foreground service to receive location updates any time the location changes more than a certain distance from the previous report (callback), but it isn't clear how to do that. I would also like it to have a maximum interval between updates.

So, the logic is: update if location_change >= Z or time_since_last_callback >= T.

The code below is not satisfying the distance parameter, but then the API only has a minimum, not a maximum setting, as far as I can tell.

```
private LocationRequest makeLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10*60*1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50);
    return locationRequest;
}
```